# How do you make orbiting text in Davinci Resolve 15?

Tags: video, video-editor, animation, davinci-resolve, fusion

[Spinning globe with orbiting texts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyFVzZWhLQs)

Does someone know how to make the orbiting text shown at the bottom right corner of the linked clip or where to such a tutorial online by using Davinci Resolve?

Comment: I suspect that there is a more "professional" way to do this using Fusion but I can't speak to that. I can show you a quick and dirty way to do it using an animated PNG in a post below though. I hope that helps.

Comment: DaVinci Resolve and Fusion aren't designed for creating 3d assets.  For that, you'll need something like blender, 3ds max, cinema 4d, etc.  Fusion has basic 3d primitives built in, but for something like a globe, you're going to want to import an asset as alembic or fbx into fusion.  From there, you can do some animation, but the animation toolset is still probably stronger in the 3d creation software.  Fusion's strength lies with compositing.  Think of it more like photoshop for moving images (actually, after effects).  The difference there is that fusion is node-based instead of layer based.

Comment: But the best tutorials on BMD fusion are from Vito's Con-Fusion series.  In this one, he shows how to make a 3D object by extruding it.  It uses an external plugin, and a different version of fusion, but if you could work out how to then bend the extruded object, you could achieve the effect you're after.  But realistically, there are so many solutions to your question that I think you should watch a lot of Fusion tutorials to get a better idea of what it does, and then come back to VPSE with a more narrowly-scoped question.  https://youtu.be/qUPZookRYGY

Comment: The "The Visual Effects Guide" (for Resolve 18) has "Lesson 10 Designing 3D Broadcast Graphics" that seems to explain what you are after

Answer (score 0):

I can put this in a video tutorial later if you need it but here is what I did to achieve an effect like that. I took an animated PNG and recorded a 20 second clip of it doing its thing on the my screen. The PNG was a bouncing Firefox logo and by default is was a transparent animation but I used IrfanView to play the animation, which gave it a solid black background for recording.

[image]

Next I imported the clip into Resolve, added it to the video track above the main video, sized and positioned it to the lower left of the screen. Next I went into the color grading page and removed all the black (background) from the animated clip, which left just the bouncing logo over the original video.

This end result is not perfect because I put this together fast to answer your question. But this is what I ended up with in less than a half hour of effort.

[Bouncing Firefox Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXHGfrtvQn4)

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that "Effects" are in some cases a multi-step process.

In this case, you need first a spinning globe with spinning text.

Use a free program like Blender.org and look for some tutorials using words like this: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=universal+logo+style+blender+tutorial

You need to export the logo in a way that can be cut away transparently in Resolve.

One option is to render the background with a pure green color.

But Resolve also accepts PNG image sequences with transparent backgrounds.

Then import that footage in Resolve and composite it.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=davinci+resolve+green+screen